# Pattern matching the weather with Regular expression in iOS

Tags: regex

The The Bureau of Meteorology (BOM) in Australia issue Coastal Waters Forecast and I’m trying to crate a **regular expression** to extract the data in a certain pattern. The string they provide is constructed as a paragraph of text were each sentence starts with the *subject* and is then followed by a *description*. Example:

> Winds: Northeasterly 20 to 30 knots becoming westerly 10 to 20 knots                 early in the morning. Seas: 1.5 to 2.5 metres, decreasing to 1 to 2 metres during the morning. 1st Swell: Northeasterly 2 to 3 metres, decreasing to 1 to 2 metres during the morning. 2nd Swell: Westerly around 1 metre. Weather: Cloudy. The chance of fog in the morning with reduced visibility. Near 100% chance of rain. The chance of a thunderstorm in the morning and afternoon.

The following regular expressions attempts to separate the subject and description into two capture groups:

```
([^:]*)((?<=\s)[\w'-]*[^:])
```

like so:

**Winds**: *Northeasterly 20 to 30 knots becoming westerly 10 to 20 knots early in the morning.*

But it is not working. Please can you assist me?
The subject capture mostly works, by matching everything but a colon. The difficulty is the description matching. Sentence can begin with numbers “1st”, contain periods within them “1.5 to 2.5 metres” and the last subject of “Weather” is broken over two sentence.

Comment: How are subjects split from each other? By a new line character `\n`? Could you add another subject two your example and what expected output should be, please?

Comment: The lines are not split as such. They are sentence and end with the a full stop.The capture groups are "{Subject}: {Description}."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/zJ3vY0/3):

```
\s*([\w ]+):\s*((?:(?!\.\s*[\w ]+:).)+\.)
```

You can see the matched groups in the right panel named `Match Information`.

Breakdown:

```
\s*                         // don't match spaces before subjects
([\w ]+)                    // match subjects
:
\s*                         // don't match spaces before descriptions
(
    (?:                     // ignore group
        (?!                 // match anything not followed by a subject
            \.\s*[\w ]+:
        ).
    )+
    \.                      // match eliminated full stop
)                           // match descriptions
```

This also works if there are no spaces around subjects, descriptions and/or colons.

Comment: Wow, this looks good and I will test it soon. Thank you for making the effort.